# How to implement nested json to database SQLite?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, flutter, dart

I am currently developing an app that includes nested class, Before I didnt start to set up SQLite database for my app, I was storing nested class in maps, But now I have to use Json format to store those datas. I shared nested class below..

1. How can I make those nested classes jsonString ?

```
class CategoryModel{
  CategoryModel(
    {this.categoryId, this.categoryImagePath, this.categoryName,this.categoryColor,this.subCategoryModels});
  final int categoryColor;
  List<SubCategoryModel> subCategoryModels=[];
  int categoryId;
  String categoryImagePath;
  String categoryName;


class SubCategoryModel {
  SubCategoryModel({
    this.subCategoryId,
    this.subCategoryImagePath,
    this.subCategoryName,
    this.categoryColor,
    this.recipeId,
    List<Ingredient>ingredients,
    this.recipePhotoDir,
    this.recipeTextFromSpeechProcessing,
    this.recordedVoiceDir,
    bool isCompeted});

  final Color categoryColor;
  final double recipeId;
  bool isCompleted;
  int subCategoryId;
  String subCategoryImagePath;
  String subCategoryName;
  List<Ingredient> ingredients = [];
  String recipeTextFromSpeechProcessing;
  String recipePhotoDir;
  String recordedVoiceDir;

class Ingredient{
  Ingredient({this.ingredientName,this.dropDownValue, this.ingredientAmount});
  final ingredientName;
  String dropDownValue;
  String ingredientAmount;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'ingredientName': ingredientName,
      'dropDownValue': dropDownValue,
      'ingredientAmount': ingredientAmount,
    };
  }
```

2)When user add main category just CategoryModel object will be createdso, How can I take data from database in every user step?

Lastly, I share DbProvider class below.

```
class DBProvider {
  DBProvider._();
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();
  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null)
      return _database;

    // if _database is null we instantiate it
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }
  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "TestDB.db");
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {
    }, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE categoryModels ("
          "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          "Json String TEXT,"
          "categoryImagePath TEXT,"
          "categoryName TEXT"")");
    });
  }
  Future<void> insertCategoryModels(CategoryModel categoryModel)async{
    final Database db = await database;

    await db.insert('categoryModels', categoryModel.toJson(),conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }
  Future<List<CategoryModel>> getCategoryModels() async {
    // Get a reference to the database.
    final Database db = await database;

    // Query the table for all The Dogs.
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('categoryModels');

    // Convert the List<Map<String, dynamic> into a List<Dog>.
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return CategoryModel(
        categoryId: maps[i]['categoryId'],
        categoryColor: maps[i]['categoryColor'],
        categoryImagePath: maps[i]['categoryImagePath'],
        categoryName:  maps[i]['categoryName'],
        subCategoryModels:maps[i]['subCategoryModels']
      );
    });
  }
  Future<int> getCategoryModelsLenght()async{
    final Database db = await database;
    // Query the table for all The Dogs.
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('categoryModels');
    return maps.length;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is relational DB management system. The data you are expecting from JSON is mostly NoSQL(Key-Value) type. If you are expecting data like nested JSON, then you may have only two ways of doing this using SQFLite.

- Either save the nested class data as JSON string and parse every time the object is referenced.
- Or you need to make a table which will reference the values while querying the data from table. Like Category table has subCategory with id 2. So while getting or setting do the required task to process all referenced tables.

Actually I would suggest the second option if you are asking. because data integrity will not loss in this way. But you should also consider using NoSQL databases like

- [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)
- [Sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast)

Answer (score 0):

Try this flutter plugin [json_store](https://pub.dev/packages/json_store)